# SQL Query to find LIKE from a ACf Field within a Custom Post Type

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a Custom Post Type (CPT) created called "person". Each record has a title (i.e. John Smith) and two custom fields create with ACF (named 'first name and 'last name'). The Post Title and first name and last name fields allow for independent entries (i.e The Post Title for display purposes might be "Ringo" but the first name could be Richard and the last name Starky). Anyway, I created an alphabet search index which works:

```
global $wpdb;
$yourposts = $wpdb->get_results( 
    $wpdb->prepare( 
        "
            SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
            WHERE post_title LIKE %s
            AND post_type = 'person'
            AND post_status = 'publish'
        ",
            $_GET['letter'] . '%' 
        )
    
);
```

Which I then display in a standard loop. But as you can see in WHERE statement it is search on the Post Title (Ringo) I need the query to search all the post_type for person within the Act custom field called last name. I have tried variations of substituting:

```
WHERE post_title LIKE
```

with

```
WHERE meta_key= 'last name' LIKE
```

but nothing seems to work. Anyone have any suggestions or would be so kind as to point out what Im doing wrong please?

Answer (score 1):

The ACF field is stored in a different table like wp_post_meta or in wp_options.

According to you your first name and last name are stored in the wp_post_meta table.

And each field is stored in a different row in this table. So we need to join tables to get data from both tables in a single query.

To get a single row from wp_post_meta (ie first name with post title) we need to join one time. if we need two rows on a single row then we need to join wp_post_meta two times ( ie get first_name and last_name with post_title.

> SELECT a.post_title, b.meta_value as first_meta_value, c.meta_value as last_meta_value FROM wp_posts as a left JOIN wp_postmeta as b on a.id=b.post_id AND b.meta_key='first_name' left JOIN wp_postmeta as c on a.id=b.post_id AND c.meta_key='last_name' WHERE a.post_title LIKE '%' AND a.post_type = 'person' AND a.post_status = 'publish';

Here I have assigned wp_posts AS a wp_post_meta As b for the first join, and for the second join wp_post_meta As c.

You can change the meta_key value according to your data And You can change '%' to your prepare data

Add

> a.post_title, b.meta_value as first_meta_value, c.meta_value as
> last_meta_value

To make distinct meta_value for first_name and last_name meta_key. You can add more according to your requirement.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did not actually need to JOIN with post_id as I only needed the last name. But yoru answer made me realize that the field I was looking for was in a separate table as you mentioned. I finally decided on a simpler approach and just find the last word of the post title (which would wind up being the same as the sepearte field 'last name" any way...

Comment: SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
            WHERE RIGHT(post_title, LOCATE(' ', REVERSE(post_title)) - 1) LIKE %s
            AND post_type = 'person'
   AND post_status = 'publish'